# How to fix this error from a semicolon which seems to be unfixable?

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft

Here's all my code:

```
@Override
public void onEnable()
{
    getLogger().info("Plugin Enabled!");

    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args)
    {
        if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Plugin"))
        { 
            // If the player typed /plugin then do the following...
            if (sender instanceof Player) 
            {
                Player player = (Player) sender;

                // Gives player item
                return true;
            } 
            else 
            {
                sender.sendMessage("You must be a player!");
                return false;
            }
        }   
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisable() 
    {
        getLogger().info("Plugin Disabled!");
    }
}
```

In case you didn't know, this is a plugin for Minecraft Bukkit.

Here's the error line:

```
getLogger().info("Plugin Enabled!");
```

When I delete the semicolon, the message in " " is an error, and when I insert a "}" or/and a "{" it shows an error.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a method (`onCommand`) within another method (`onEnable`) - this is not possible.

I suppose you are missing a closing brace `}` before `public boolean onCommand`.

```
public void onEnable() {
    getLogger().info("Plugin Enabled!");
} //HERE ADD THE MISSING BRACE

public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
    if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Plugin")) { // If the player typed /plugin then do the following...
        if (sender instanceof Player) {
            Player player = (Player) sender;

            // Gives player item
            return true;
        } else {
            sender.sendMessage("You must be a player!");
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false; //HERE YOU NEED TO RETURN FROM THE ELSE TOO
    }
}
```

Comment: Then where do i put the (onCommand) assylias?

Comment: That fixed the problem but i'm still getting errors at the semicolon on "return false;"

Comment: `onCommand` needs to return something when `if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Plugin")))` is false.

Comment: @user2015563 See my new edit.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have 3 methods: `onEnable()`, `onCommand()` and `onDisable()` however the two last methods are defined within `onEnable()` which you cannot do. if you put a '}' after the `getLogger()...` call you will end the `onEnable()` call there, then you also need to remove the trailing '}' you got at the end of the block you are showing us.

Comment: Ok, but then i get an error on the ";" on the "return false;" at the end

Comment: @user2015563 - you need to take some basic Java programming classes. These issues are ***very*** basic.

Comment: Ahh yes but that is because the method onCommand() must return either true or false. but if the first if statement fails `if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Plugin"))` then the method returns nothing, add a return statement in end of the `onCommand()` method and that should take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onEnable(){
    getLogger().info("Plugin Enabled!");
}// Add braces

    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args){
        if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Plugin")){ // If the player typed /plugin then do the following...
            if (sender instanceof Player) {
                   Player player = (Player) sender;

                   // Gives player item
                   return true;
                } else {
                   sender.sendMessage("You must be a player!");
                   return false;
                }
        } 

    }

@Override
public void onDisable() {
    getLogger().info("Plugin Disabled!");
}
// } Delete this braces
```